# Ubuntu 10.10 how to change/create password keyring

Tags: passwords, ubuntu-10.10, gnome-keyring

when I try to remote desktop to the server from another ubuntu machine using the remote desktop viewer, it asks me to enter the password, which I do, then the viewer pane just goes black. When I come back and look at my server it is saying that the password keyring no longer matches the password used to login to the machine please reenter the password...and when I type in the password it doesnt take it, it just keeps popping back up saying the same message over and over.

I found a thread explaining to go to System-->Preferences-->Passwords & Encryptions and right click on the keyring and click Set as Default.

I did that and the problem persists...I tried changing the password but it told me that my original password was incorrect (even though it is the password I use to login and provide root authentication when asked)

so I deleted the keyring in hopes of adding a new one but there is no place in gui to add a new one...so can I add a new one through command line?

if so - how?